# Can both AC ground and DC ground connect to the same Ground STUD

Tags: aircraft-systems, electrical-system, electronics, airframe-and-powerplant

Can both AC ground and DC ground connect to the same Ground STUD in a plane?

Comment: what kind of planes are you interested in?

Comment: It looks like you're asking whether *when you need to connect AC and DC generators to the ground* you can use the same stud. But as you know all studs are already connected by the aircraft frame and are equipotential (ignoring frame impedance). So I'm wondering if you're asking something else, e.g. if you need to connect both AC and DC to the ground, or if this is mechanically safe. It's not clear.

Answer (score 7):

I am assuming you are referring to whether or not it is acceptable to connect the ground side of an AC supply and a DC supply to a common ground stud on the airframe. According to the FAA's [Aircraft Electrical Wiring Interconnect System job aid, revision 2.0, page 116](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/training/air_training_program/job_aids/media/ewis_job-aid_2.0_printable.pdf)(PDF):

> **Grounding types**: AC returns, DC returns, and others.
>
> **Mixing return currents**. If wires carrying return currents from  different types of sources, such as signals or DC and AC generators, are connected to the same  ground point or have a common connection in the return  paths, an interaction of  the currents will occur.  ***This interaction may not be a problem, or it could be a major non-repeatable anomaly.*** 
> <sup>Emphasis added.</sup>
>
> • To minimize the interaction between various return  currents, different types of grounds should  be identified and used.  As a minimum, the design should use  three ground types:  (1) AC returns, (2) DC returns, and (3) all others.
>
> • For distributed power systems, the power return point for an alternative power source would be separated.

Answer (score 1):

Good practise advices to avoid mixing AC and DC returns in order to do not have noise coupling which can be dangerous for digital systems.
Keep in mind that EMI problems linked to system's power wire can be reduced by locating the power return near the aircraft circuit braker panel (twisting positive and negative wires can help too).

Answer (score 0):

If you put your grounds together, and you have gnd and neutral reversed at a plug in the 120/240 side,  Inverter will see a dead short and fry MOFSET's. I just fried 2 inverters doing it. DC does not need an earth ground except to the case ground lug on the inverter.

I had AC/DC using a common ground spike. 120v sockets were wired with N and Gnd wired wrong. System was fine until I united the gnd's. 40a DC Fuses blew and 30a
120 breaker tripped on breaker panel. Inverter has dead short and MOFSET'S overheated cracking the insulator on some, others had discoloration at solder joints and circuit board traces @ source and drain.

Comment: is this answer for a house or an aircraft, which do not normally have a ground spike?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).